Custom plugin in nuxt 3 has unknown type
In my nuxt 3 application, I have created a plugin in plugins/ folder.
// plugins/customPlugin.ts

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => ({
   provide: {
      hello: (msg: string) => console.log(`This is your message: ${msg}`),
   },
}));

And then I am using it in my component like:
// component.vue 

const { $hello } = useNuxtApp();

$hello('custom message');

It works, in the browser console I see my log.
But the problem is, that the typescript gives me an error in IDE, saying that $hello is "TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'"
Tried to delete node modules and .nuxt folders and reinstall them, didn't work.

try running npm run postinstall

UPDATE: Turns out that there is a bug in jetbrains IDEs (Phpstorm, webstorm). Tried opening same repo in vscode, plugins are typed OK
About bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-59818/Vue-custom-global-properties-added-by-augmenting-vue-are-not-resolved

This method works for me.
~/plugins/<filename>.ts:
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  function hello(name: string) {
    return `Hello ${name}`
  }
  return { provide: { hello } }
})

<script lang="ts" setup>
const { $hello } = useNuxtApp();
const output = $hello('custom message');
</script>

When you hover over the $hello it will show the typing:

OR
Another way to get the correct typing based on the typing plugins documentation
index.d.ts:
declare module '#app' {
  interface NuxtApp {
    $hello(msg: string): string
  }
}
export { }


Nope, still doesn't work. I think the problem is in my IDE / ts settings
